# How to get result in android phonegap plugin

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to create a phonegap plugin for android, I'm getting the result properly but when I'm trying to perform validation, I'm not able to fetch the errors appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending the result back i have the option to decide if the result is ok or it is a error, So i have to do it like this

```
return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK,"Login Successful");


return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,"Login Failed");
```

Comment: So OK will invoke the success function and the ERROR will invoke the error function which we would have to define right

Comment: Yes while calling your plugin you have to define the successfunction errorfunction and the input if u have any for your call and the action to the plugin which you wish to perform